# Cytoscape element is added but not rendered

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

So I want to render the following Cytoscape element but in the end there is nothing that appears on the screen.

```
let cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    elements: [ // list of graph elements to start with
        { // node a
            data: { id: 'a' }
        },
        { // node b
            data: { id: 'b' }
        },
        { // edge ab
            data: { id: 'ab', source: 'a', target: 'b' }
        },
        {
            data: { id: 'c' }
        },
        {
            data: {
                id: 'ac', source: 'a', target: 'c',
                'value': 'ceva',
                'value2': 'data(target)',
            }
        }
    ],

    style: [ // the stylesheet for the graph
        {
            selector: 'node',
            style: {
                'background-color': 'red',
                'label': 'data(id)'
            }
        },

        {
            selector: 'edge',
            style: {
                'width': 3,
                'line-color': 'blue',
                'target-arrow-color': '#ccc',
                'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                'curve-style': 'bezier',
            }
        }
    ],

    layout: {
        name: 'grid',
        rows: 1
    }
})
cy.add([
    { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n0' }, position: { x: 100, y: 100 } },
    { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n1' }, position: { x: 200, y: 200 } },
    { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e0', source: 'n0', target: 'n1' } }
]);
```

This is the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
    <script src="./cyto.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What the problem seems to me is the fact that the Cytoscape class ends up having the height = 0. After I modify the class in inspect element and add height = 1000px it works mostly fine.
What could the solution be, I am new to Cytoscape so I think this might be a basic mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using cytoscape with this kind of setup:

```
<div id="cy" style="width: 900px; height: 800px;"></div>
```

where height and width are set at the beginning.